# What is the reference for PowerShell in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, namespaces

I tried to run a PowerShell script in C#. But it throws and error :

```
PowerShell doesn't available in current context.
```

I searched in google but i didn't get the solution, please help. This is my code :

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Backup Reporter\Required\edit_website.ps1");    
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
    // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(text);

    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Error");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download System.Management.Automation and attach it to your project:

https://www.nuget.org/profiles/PowerShellTeam

Comment: i have installed System.Management.Automation.dll . But error not removed.

Comment: Did you refer to it above your namespace? `using System.Management.Automation;`

Comment: Check if the dll is located in: C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191155/discussion-between-gopal-and-sebastian).

Answer (score 0):

Download and Add the packages of **System.Management.Automation** and **System.Management.Automation.Runspaces** from VS Nuget Manager to your project.

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/executing-powershell-from-c/

Answer (score 0):

`PowerShell` class exists in **Windows PowerShell SDK 1.1.0** that you to your project with this NuGet package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/

```
PM> Install-Package System.Management.Automation -Version 6.2.0
```